# The sound in Regal's RPX Theatre's

Tags: playback

Regal just built a brand new theatre in my area and along with IMAX it has it's own brand of theatre called RPX (Regal Premium Experience).

I have an inside friend who got a chance to watch a movie in the RPX theatre before it opened, and she was amazed at how it sounded. She even suggested it was better then other theatre's in town (also owned buy Regal, but not RPX).

I'm wondering what goes into the playback of the sound in one of these RPX theatre's?  Is it different then the standard Dolby, or DTS playback systems? Is it just a marketing tool to get people to buy tickets?

I checked the Regal site, and it gives no technical information.  So I figured I'd ask around here to see if anyone knows more about the sound technology inside a Regal RPX!

Edit: I've since learned one RPX in NYC is a 9.1 system.

Comment: Likely a marketing tool.  I've been to Arclights, Regals, and some others and their 'preimuim' offerings and hardly ever are those rooms calibrated (usually over calibrated - I feel bad for those who are in the front 2/3 of the theater when this happens).  I'm not shooting it down entirely, but I am calling suspicion to it based upon my past experiences with 'premium' offerings.

Comment: The lack of technical info provided is telling...